# Canonical colorings over $ \omega $

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Given a natural number n, let $ c:[X]^n \to \omega $ be a coloring by arbitrary many colors, where $X$ is an infinite countable set. Then there exists an infinite subset $ H $ of $ X $ for which the restriction of $ c $ to $ [H]^n $ is canonical. Meaning that for such restriction we have a fixed set $I\subseteq \lbrace 1,2,3,\ldots ,n \rbrace$ such that : $c(x_1\leq \cdots \leq x_n)=c(y_1\leq \cdots \leq y_n)$ if and only if $x_i=y_i$ for $i\in I$.

I'm looking for a proof of this, but I've been unable to find it. I think it might be analogous to the proof for Theorem 4.8, [p. 1367](https://books.google.com/books?id=5ktBP5vUl5gC&pg=PA1367) in Grahams Handbook of Combinatorics, Volume 1. which reads:

> **Theorem 4.8.** (Canonical Lemma, Erdős and Rado, 1952) For every choice of positive integers $p$, $n$ there exists $N(p,n)$ such that for every set $ X $, $ |X| \geq N(p,n)$ and for every coloring $c:[X]^p \to \mathbb{N}$ (i.e. coloring by arbitrary many colors) there exists a set $ Y \subseteq X $, $ |Y|\geq n $, such that the coloring $ c $ restricted to the set $ [Y]^p $ is canonical.
>
> Here a coloring $c$ is said to be *canonical* if there exists a set $\omega\subseteq p$ such that
>   $$c(x_1<\dots<x_p)=c(x_1'<\dots<x_p'\text{ iff } x_i=x_i'\text{ for } i\in\omega.$$
>   (Thus there are $2^p$ canonical coloring patterns.)

But a proof of this isn't provided in the text.

Comment: There is something key missing at the end of your first paragraph.

Comment: Specifically "if and only if $(x_i)$" makes no sense as is.  Perhaps some additional math formula was left off?

Comment: The statement in your first paragraph seems to be trivial because you can take $H=\emptyset.$ (If $X=\emptyset$ then $H=\emptyset$ is the only possible choice for $H.$) Did you leave out something about the cardinalities of $X$ and $H$?